# Selecting certain keys in a Hash

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash `h` and want to have an Array of those keys, where their values fulfil a certain condition.  My naive approach is:

```
result = h.select { |_, val| val.fulfils_condition? }.keys
```

This works, of course, but looks unnecessarily inefficient to me, as it requires an intermediate Hash to be constructed, from which then the result Array is calculated.

Of course I could do an explicit loop:

```
result = []
h.each do
  |key, val|
  result << key if val.fulfils_condition?
end
```

but this I consider ugly due to the explicit handling of `result`. I also was contemplating this one:

```
result = h.reduce([]) do
  |memo, pair| 
  memo << pair.first if pair.last.fulfils_condition?
  memo
end
```

but this is not really more readable, and requires the construction of the intermediate `pair` arrays, each holding a key-value-pair.

Is there an alternative approach, which is compact, and does not need to calculate a  temporary Hash?

Comment: Is the intermediate hash actually a problem? You have valid solutions - if it's a a critical inner loop, go with efficient and ugly. If it's not, go with succinct and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
h = {}; (1..100).each {|v| h[v.to_s] = v }
```

You can use the memory_profiler gem to measure allocations. Use something like `MemoryProfiler.report { code }.total_allocated`.

If memory allocations are *really* at a premium here, your approach of preallocating the result and then enumerating with `#each` is what you want. The reason for this is that Ruby [optimizes Hash#each for blocks with an arity of 2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/245ed57ddc93901e90388cf479968392299d1067/hash.c#L3158-L3161), so that a new array isn't constructed per loop. The only allocation in this approach is the results array.

```
MemoryProfiler.report { r = [] ; h.each {|k, v| r << k if v > 1 } }.total_allocated
# => 1
```

Using `#reduce`, OTOH, results in an allocation per loop because you break the arity rule:

```
MemoryProfiler.report { h.reduce([]) {|agg, (k, v)| agg << k if v > 1 ; agg } }.total_allocated
# => 101
```

If you want something more "self-contained" and are willing to sacrifice an extra allocation, you'll want to use `#each_key` (which does create an intermediate array of keys) and then index into the hash to test each value.

```
h.each_key.select {|k| h[k] > 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple is best I think. How about this?

```
h.keys.select { |k| k.meets_condition }
```

Comment: the condition is on value, not on key

Comment: Can you not use `.select { |_k,v| v.meets_condition }` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I love @ChrisHeald solution

```
h.each_key.filter_map { |k| k if condition(h[k]) }
```

I would have gone with a more verbose

```
h.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), arr| arr < k if condition(v) }
```

or even

```
h.map { |k, v| k if condition(v) }.compact
```

which are clearly constructing more than needed, but are still quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off Peter Camilleri's proposal, I think the following does what you want:

```ruby
h = {:a => 1, :b => -1, :c => 2, :d => -2}
h.keys.select { |k| h[k] < 0 }  # [:b, :d]
```

Comment: Can you not use `.select { |k,v| v < 0 }` instead?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Not the same. That yields a hash containing the keys and values of the targeted elements rather than an array of just the keys, as requested. Fire up `irb` or `pry` and try it both ways to see.

Comment: Ah, if you just want the keys, just add `.keys` afterwards like `h.select { |k,v| v < 0 }.keys #=> [:b, :d]`